# How to create RewriteRule for the specific match https and www together?

Tags: apache, ssl, url-rewriting, virtualhost

I have managed to create working redirects for www and for non-www (plain http) and https, but when using them together it doesn't work anymore. I have four domains and want each one to redirect to a base-domain and then add url parameters.

**Right now the current result when trying the different variations:**

```
www.example.fi -> redirects me to https://example.se/?lang=fi. OK
http://example.fi -> redirects me to https://example.se/?lang=fi OK
https://example.fi -> redirects me to https://example.se/?lang=fi OK
https://www.example.fi -> redirects me to https://example.se without the lang parameters.  WRONG. It should take me to the same place as the other.
```

**This is my http virtual host:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.fi
ServerAlias example.fi
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dir
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Redirect permanent / https://example.se/?lang=fi
</VirtualHost>
```

**And this is my https:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.fi
ServerAlias example.fi
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dir
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/user/example.fi.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user/example.fi.key
SSLCACertificateFile /home/user/intermediate.pem
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.fi$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.se%{REQUEST_URI}/\?lang=fi [R=301,L]
```

As you can see, i want the different language domains point to the SE-domain with the language parameter.

How can i modify my code so that it matches with all possible variations of https, http and www together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.fi$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://example.se%{REQUEST_URI}/\?lang=fi [R=301,L]
```

the Rewrite match only htt(s)://exemple.fi URL

Without ^ it should work

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.fi$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://example.se%{REQUEST_URI}/\?lang=fi [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved most of my problems.. however now i have a new one unfortunately. Probably a simple solution but if i now go to example.fi/test, i get redirected to example.se/?lang=fitest. How can i make sure that my /test/ gets before the lang parameter?

Comment: i think it's because of the RedirectPermeanent in your virtualHost , you can try to change it to Redirect permanent / https://example.se/

Comment: That didn't solve the problem but i added the same rewrite rule to :80 as i had on :443 but i added RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off. Is this bad practise? It seems to be working in most of the cases but sometimes i get a fallback to the plain .se domain for unknown reasons.

Comment: Not a Bad pratice to me
For me rewriterule is more usefull than Redirect permanent  (you can use %{REQUEST_URI} )